# Impossible to list all posts of one category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

I've tried many things ... but I can't list all posts of categories in category.php. Even when I specifying the id directly Wordpress never found my posts ('No post' in the page). However, I can list all my posts and show the category to which they belong.

My code in **category.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="page">

  <h1 class="page__title"><?php if (is_category()){
    single_cat_title('');
  }?></h1>

  <?php
  $current_cat_id  = get_query_var('cat');
  $args = array('cat' => $current_cat_id, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC');
  query_posts($args);

  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
  <?php the_title();?>

  <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php _e('No post.'); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Add wp_reset_query() after wihile loop

Comment: Thanks. But I try this many times before... it doesn't work :/

Comment: I've tried your code on my wp template and it works. What is result if you put empty args = array()  ?